# method variable passed changes to null

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

I do work on a legacy application which uses multi-threading to improve processing. I am facing an unusual error where i do get the value passed as method argument as null when i am passing a string.

```
 Trace.error("Thread-"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"-"+Thread.currentThread().getId()+ ": TransactionAudit-request.validateRequest: "+mContext.get("request.validateRequest"));
    rta.setValidateRequest((String) mContext.get("request.validateRequest"));

public void setValidateOnly(String mValidateRequest) {
    Trace.getTracer().error("Thread-"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"-"+Thread.currentThread().getId()+": Transactionaudit-request.validateRequest: "+mValidateRequest);
    this.mValidateRequest = mValidateRequest;
}
```

In the first two lines i am logging and setting the value in an object.
In the next method log the variable which is set.
However this is where something unusual happens.

```
Thread-DocumentValidationTPOOL49-373: TransactionAudit-request.validateRequest: false 
Thread-DocumentValidationTPOOL27-351: CommwithPP.Resent.request.validateRequest: null
```

As you can see above the value when the setter is called is false whereas when i log it from inside the setter method it is null.
I would add that this is a application which handles high number of requests usually hundreds of transactions per minute. Can this be anything related to memory related to thread execution in java.

Comment: I don't think this is enough code to be able to answer this question. What is mContext? Looks like there's no value for key "request.validateRequest" in your mContext map. Or that value is null.

Comment: mContext is a POJO which is created for every request where the first line of the log proves that it has the value.

Comment: From where setValidateOnly is being called. Can you paste the corresponding snippet as well.

Comment: I am unable to paste the calling code as it is proprietary. Also as a description of what the method does is simply setting the value using the value from mcontext. However i can add that the values are stored in a Hashmap. Can this be a scenario where multiple threads accessing the same value causing it to return null.

Comment: Which map you are using? HashMap - If yes, it is not thread safe. SynchronizedMap  - When the data is added, is it added by a different thread ConcurrentHashMap - It may be a case that race condition has occured. Reason can be that read and write are happening on the same segment at same time.

Answer (score 0):

If not thread-safe object is shared between multiple threads it's not guaranteed that updates performed in one thread will be visible by other threads. In your case one thread sets `false` but other still see `null` which was set during an object initialization. You should share your object between threads properly. Consider to use `volatile` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the rehashing of the hashmap which is performed when new elements are inserted and at this particular moment if any of the thread requests for the value then there is a possibility that the map may return null. This turned out to be a good usecase emphasizing the need to use thread safe collections in multi-threaded environment.